# Apache jena 3.4.0 database error during data phase

Tags: sparql, ttl, fuseki

I am trying to generate a new database using `tdbloader2` using the command:

```bash
/opt/apache-jena-3.4.0/bin/tdbloader2 \
  --loc /fuseki/databases/blue/DS-DB \
  /var/lib/data/work/time-stamp.nt \
  /var/lib/data/work/Output/*.ttl \
  /var/lib/data/work/ReferenceData/*.ttl \
  /var/lib/data/work/vocabs/*.ttl
```

The error I get is:

```bash
...
INFO  Load: /var/lib/data/work/ReferenceData/SAMPLING_POINT_TYPES.ttl -- 2024/03/04 00:01:17 UTC                                                                                                           
INFO  Load: /var/lib/data/work/ReferenceData/UNITS.ttl -- 2024/03/04 00:01:17 UTC                                                                                                                          
INFO  Load: /var/lib/data/work/vocabs/determinand.ttl -- 2024/03/04 00:01:17 UTC                                                                                                                      
INFO  Load: /var/lib/data/work/vocabs/ea-org.ttl -- 2024/03/04 00:01:17 UTC                                                                                                                           
INFO  Load: /var/lib/data/work/vocabs/intentional-determinand-groups.ttl -- 2024/03/04 00:01:17 UTC                                                                                                   
INFO  Load: /var/lib/data/work/vocabs/result-qualifiers.ttl -- 2024/03/04 00:01:17 UTC                                                                                                                
INFO  Load: /var/lib/data/work/vocabs/sample.ttl -- 2024/03/04 00:01:17 UTC                                                                                                                           
INFO  Load: /var/lib/data/work/vocabs/sampling-point-status.ttl -- 2024/03/04 00:01:17 UTC                                                                                                            
INFO  Load: /var/lib/data/work/vocabs/sampling-point.ttl -- 2024/03/04 00:01:17 UTC                                                                                                                   
INFO  Load: /var/lib/data/work/vocabs/unit.ttl -- 2024/03/04 00:01:17 UTC                                                                                                                             
INFO  Total: 389,245,433 tuples : 4,012.31 seconds : 97,012.73 tuples/sec [2024/03/04 00:01:21 UTC]                                                                                                                
 00:01:22 INFO Data Load Phase Completed                                                                                                                                                                           
 00:01:22 INFO Index Building Phase                                                                                                                                                                                
 00:01:22 INFO Creating Index SPO                                                                                                                                                                                  
 00:01:22 INFO Sort SPO                                                                                                                                                                                            
/opt/apache-jena-3.4.0/bin/tdbloader2index: line 306: 63100 Killed                  sort $SORT_ARGS -u $KEYS < "$DATA" > $WORK                                                                                     
 00:02:28 ERROR Failed during data phase
```

I expect the database to be correctly generated and the command to complete successfully.

There is a lot of data in these `*.ttl` files to work with, total of 2050 and most around 10M in size each (I have tried this with a much smaller sample and it works just fine). I have tried this on a machine with 32G of memory, so I don't think that is an issue, certainly not from what I can tell from the error message at least.

I also tried the same thing on a machine with a GPU processor and 64G of memory and the same thing, so I'm pretty sure it's nothing to do with the GPU/CPU or Memeory. However, I am completely stuck on what it could be, so any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, first of all I must ask: any reason for using Jena 3.4.0? We're close to Jena 5.0.0, but at least there is Jena 4.10.0

Comment: from the cut error message it looks like the `sort` operation of the index failed, maybe due to OOM. Are you using Linux or Windows? Did you try to increase the Java heap space for Jena?

Comment: I am using Jena 3.4.0 as this is a fairly old app we are migrating. To start with, we want to keep it as similar to the old hosted site as possible.

Comment: @UninformedUser I was of the impression (probably wrong) that fuseki itself doesn't need to be running for the `tdbloader2` command to be run. Do you know if I'm wrong in that assumption? If fuseki itself doesn't need to be running, can we increase the heap space and if it is necessary, how and where would I do that? I'm familiar with setting it on a Java command, but not for fuseki tools.

Comment: I have been playing with this and it must be to do with the number of files or memory. I reduced the number of files down until it worked, which ended up at 280, a far cry from the 2050 plus that it needs to be able to work with.

Comment: It could be a `ulimit` process limit.
Combing the files first into large chunks and fewer files can help.

Comment: I did check `ulimit` and it is a stupidly large  number of files allowed. The problem appears to be that I don't have enough memory on my machine to do the in-memory sort, so it is resorting to disk-based and even then, I didn't have enough disk-space. Basically my dev machine is too limited.

Answer (score 1):

So as I stated in my last comment I think it is a case that my dev VM didn't have enough disk-space/memory to do this task. I've been given access to another VM with more resources and so far I haven't experienced this again. Continual battle between devs and infrastructure...

Comment: So, looks like you could solve the issue in the meantime? Also, can you share some numbers regarding the size of the data and the available memory of your machine once it worked. GNU `sort` is really efficient, but even that needs either in-memory or disk space for spilling. I can imagine that just having a tiny dev VM quite often makes development "difficult" up to impossible.

Comment: I have 22G of TTL files that are used to generate the Fuseki dbase. 

I have a total of 28G memory on my dev VM, not sure how much fuseki tools were trying to use and I had 95G of hard-disk space. It could be I had less disk-space though, I cleared the likes of /etc/cache/apt/archives etc to regain some space, I only saw the 95G after clean-up

This was all running inside a Docker VM to further complicate things, but it should be using whatever it needs from the host system, at least that is my understanding.